# Javascript - Load json from variable

Tags: javascript, json

metaModelSrc: "myfile.json" - is working great but i need a variable instead
Api receiving - A json object. theat mean that you can do metaData.name and it will show it

- when you copy paste the stringify to json file and give the path file it's working. when you are downloading the blob and give it as path file.json it does working - i need to load it from the code without downloading the blob

My error: metaModelSrc

```
Failed to load model metadata for model 'fsfdsfsdfs from  'application/json' - utils.loadJSON(): Failed to parse JSON response - SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I have tried to stringify and it didn't work i tried to turn it into a file and it didn't work.

- I have download it from a blob and i have give it a path metaModelSrc: "..../myfile.json"
  and it did work. but i need to load that from a variable and not a path and i'm not interested to download the blob, i need to work with the data that i'm getting from the api.

```
// metaData - json object from api
const metaDatastringify= JSON.stringify(metaData);
var file = new Blob([metaDatastringify], {type: 'application/json'});
var file1 = new File([file], "name", {type: 'application/json'});

    gltfLoader.load({
      id: "fsfdsfsdfs",
      metaModelSrc: file1,
      edges: true,
      performance: true,
    });
```

Comment: what are you trying to do again?

Comment: That error most likely means `metaData` is XML or HTML and cannot be parsed by the JSON API.

Comment: metaModelSrc = "myfile.json" ! it working great !
but i need myfile.json as a variable instead of a path like ",,,,/myfile.json"

Comment: Please share your API response sample.

Comment: My api response is a json object

Comment: show us metaData, it starts with `<`, so it's not a valid json

Comment: Object
metaObjects: (511) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
projectId: "myProject"
revisionId: "myRevision"
__proto__: Object

Comment: it's not json and it doesn have `<` so it is probably formatted with HTML tags

Comment: metaData.projectId - you will see - "myProject" if you will log it

Comment: metaModelSrc: "myfile.json", it's working and all good.
but i don't want to download the file i want to use it like this: metaModelSrc: var...

Comment: if it's blob it has content-type

Comment: `blob.text().then(text => /* do something with the text */);`

Comment: how do i make it work from the API response ? if the api response is json object

Comment: but it's not, it starts with `<`, maybe you are getting some syntax error from the api? check in browser developer tools what exactly are you getting in response from the api

Comment: when i'm downloading the blob to myfile.json and give it a path, it's working great.

Comment: a.download is working but with some bugs

Comment: var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
a.download is working but with some bugs *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const urlTestJsonModel = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

metaModelSrc: urlTestJsonModel
Solved my issue :) Thank you everyone for your help

Answer (score 0):

#### The error message `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` always means a particular type of error

At first I thought it was the `JSON.stringify`, but of course that is wrong. We are wrong to put our attention on the following line:

```
const metaDatastringify= JSON.stringify(metaData);
```

... and therefore on the contents of metaData.

It is not stringification that is error-prone. You can JSON.stringify almost any old nonsense.

#### Your error is in a JSON.parse

The error is occurring during this (but there is no error in this code itself):

```
gltfLoader.load({
  id: "fsfdsfsdfs",
  metaModelSrc: file1,
  edges: true,
  performance: true,
});
```

JSON.parse is always expecting to receive a string, with the first non-whitespace character being  "{".

Your JSON.parse call is not in your code, but in the code of `gltfLoader.load()`.

Examples of the distress you can get with JSON.parse:

```
// Correct call
JSON.parse('{"a":3, "b":"hello"}')
{a: 3, b: "hello"}

// Forget the quotation marks around "a"
JSON.parse(' {a:"<html>skdjfhskdf</html> "}')
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 2

// Use wrong quotation marks (JSON.parse insists on double-quotes for each key. (I have put this error message as two single quotes, to stop stack overflow turning everything that follows into a comment, but it will appear as only one single quote.)
JSON.parse(" {'a':'<html>skdjfhskdf</html> '}")
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '' in JSON at position 2

// Empty string input
JSON.parse("")
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

// Undefined - watch out for this one which is completely baffling the first time it happens! I think it is converting undefined into "undefined" for some reason?
JSON.parse(undefined)
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

// Feed in an HTML or XML string, i.e. something starting with an "<"
JSON.parse("<html>Hello</html>")
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

#### Steps to diagnose

It is the last type that you are getting. Therefore during the running of `gltfloader.load()`, a JSON.parse statement is somehow receiving an XML or HTML formatted data item.

Either the server actually sending data in that format, or it is sending an error message, such as a 404 page.

Do you have any way of reading that page, through javascript, as any other format other than via `gltfloader`?

Have you considered reading it as though it was a text file (through javascript, not through a manual route and saving it), and see what you get?

Is it the expected JSON string, or something else? I bet it is the latter.

#### Specifically we can see that the error message is not from Javascript but from code written by your or introduced by you

Failed to load model metadata for model 'fsfdsfsdfs from  'application/json' - utils.loadJSON(): Failed to parse JSON response - SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Break it down as follows.

This last part is issued by Javascript:

```
utils.loadJSON(): Failed to parse JSON response - SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

This earlier part is deliberately issued by code that is *not* the Javascript interpreter.

```
Failed to load model metadata for model 'fsfdsfsdfs from  'application/json'
```

Someone has coded that phrase "Failed to load model metadata for model". That does not exist in the Javascript interpreter. It is in some code module that was added. There is an error message which deliberately prints that and then shows the underlying Javascript error message.

The heart of the problem is a JSON.parse (*not* JSON.stringify) that is operating on an XML or HTML string, rather than a JSON string.

#### Are you sure the Javascript new File function is actually making a file and saving it on your file system?

You tell us that when you put `"myfile.json"` into metaModelSrc, the code works. This means that the code works correctly when it is reading a file from the computer's file system (i.e. a file that you can see in File Explorer or Finder or Nautilus, etc).

However, I think the javascript "new File" function does not actually save a file to your computer's hard disk, does it? Can you look to see if one is created when you run it?

Comment: JSON.parse(metaDatastringify) - i'm getting back my json object but the metaModelSrc will fail on object and this is the metaData that i receive from the api at the end

Comment: Not that line. THe last line of yor code is the problem

Comment: it's the same json file

Comment: See the last section - "Steps to Diagnose"

Comment: webpack:///./node_modules/@xeokit/xeokit-sdk/src/viewer/Plugin.js?:94 [xeokit plugin GLTFLoader]: load(): Failed to load model metadata for model 'fsfdsfsdfs from  '{"projectId":"myProject","revisionId":"myRevision","metaObjects":[{"extid":"4d17bb41e71e3cf5e23e102752fc0ee0","name":"Duplex Building","type":"IfcBuilding","uuid":"1xS3BCk291UvhgP2a6eflK","id":"1xS3BCk291UvhgP2a6eflK"},{"CassiopAttr":"LOCAL 01-01-0115-01-

Comment: Yes, i'm sure. because when i'm downloading the file and use it in my path it works

Comment: ```const urlTestJsonModel = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```
metaModelSrc: urlTestJsonModel Solved my issue :) Thank you everyone for your help